# Docx content and formatting extraction in python

Tags: python, file-io, xml-parsing, fileparsing

I am trying to parse a docx folder and take specific elements base on wether or not a certain word is bolded.  If this is the text in the document:

**Foo:** Hello

***Boo:***
Blah Blah

•Blah

•Blah

***Choo:*** Hello

I would want to scan, line by line, and take all the text after the bolded word until the next bolded word.

As of right now I am using using an XML parser that parses based on newline charactrs.  I cannot find anything in the Zipfile or the individual lines that would give me metadata like that.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: You are not looking for "file parsing in Python with Formatting" but rather for "Docx content and formatting extraction in python" or something similar. Did you look at [python-docx](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx/)?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a higher-level library that supports reading docx files rather than parsing the XML document.

One library that looks up to the task is [python-docx](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx).

If you're using Jython, [Apache POI HWPF](http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/index.html) is another option.